# Ajax Calls in Phone Gap Fails in IOS

Tags: cordova

I m trying to make Ajax Calls from my Phone Gap Application in IOS device. The Server has a valid Certificate too. But still i m not able to make the Ajax Call. Where am i missing ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added your server to the whitelist? You need to add all servers you want your app to connect to in PhoneGap.plist

Answer (score 1):

To add to what codemonkey said -

if you create a new entry in your phonegap.plist file in External Hosts and have the name be anything you want and set the value to * that will whitelist all domains.

Answer (score 1):

And what if you are using PhoneGap build and don't have any phonegap.plist file?

Comment: Have you found a solution to that yet?

Comment: Yes, I allowed access to all sites in my config.xml file with the line: <access origin="*" /> although you can just add the specific site that you need, see the "access element" section here: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml